# Angular UI Tree: remove callback not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I'm using https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree module. 
I have api that sending me array of slides, which are array of groups, which are array of graphs. So I want to draw it as a tree and add node remove confirmation and api call on removed. I wrote this code to test callbacks

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.tree']);

app.controller("DashboardCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $timeout) { 
    $scope.loadData = function() {
        $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/list')
        .then(function successCallback(data) {
            $scope.data = data.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
        });
    }     
    $scope.remove = function (node) {
        console.log("remove " + node);
    };
    $scope.removeNode = function (node) {
        console.log("removeNode " + node);
    };
    $scope.removed = function (node) {
        console.log("removed " + node);
    };
    $scope.edit = function (node) {
        console.log("edit " + node);
    };
    $scope.newSubItem = function(node) {
        console.log(node)
    };
    $scope.loadData();
}
)
```

Here is my html code:

```
<body ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div ui-tree class="angular-ui-tree" data-drag-enabled="false" data-empty-placeholder-enabled="false">
        <ol ui-tree-nodes="treeNodesOptions" ng-model="data" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid angular-ui-tree-nodes">
            <li ng-repeat="slide in data" ui-tree-node class="angular-ui-tree-node" collapsed="true">
                <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="slide.groups && slide.groups.length > 0" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)">
                        <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed }"></span>
                    </a>
                    {{slide.title}}
                    <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="removeNode(this)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="edit(this)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="slide.groups" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
                    <li ng-repeat="group in slide.groups" ui-tree-node collapsed="true">
                      <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
                          <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="slide.groups && slide.groups.length > 0" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)">
                            <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed }"></span>
                        </a>
                        {{group.title}}
                        <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="removeNode(this)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="edit(this)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="group.items" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
                        <li ng-repeat="item in group.items" ui-tree-node collapsed="true">
                          <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
                            {{item.title}}
                            <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="removeNode(this)">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="edit(this)">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

$scope.newSubItem firing with no problem, but any of remove functions not firing. Also I tried to write remove(this) instead of removeNode(this) in html. Nodes are removing fine in both cases but functions not calling.

Comment: I am the having same issue. Were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: I wrote my own function

Answer (score 1):

@Abhishek Verma

try to modify:

```
$scope.removeNode = function (node) {
   console.log("removeNode " + node);
};
```

to:

```
$scope.removeNode = function (scope) {
  scope.remove();
};
```

The function is not firing because you're not calling it, the function parameter is actually the node scope so you can access the **remove function** from there.

And you should not use:

```
ui-tree-nodes="treeNodesOptions"
```

but:

```
ui-tree-nodes=""
```

because you are not defining $scope.treeNodesOptions

cf. [Angular UI Tree collapse / remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860772/angular-ui-tree-collapse-remove)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think you just need to put the href attribute in # to your link. It was useful to me once:

```
  <a href="#" class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="removeNode(this)"></a>
```